# Adding a dynamic icon OpenCV image to Growl in Python

Tags: python, opencv, growl

I added a Growl notification to my python app which also uses OpenCV.  The basic ones work fine:

```
image = open('image.png', 'rb').read()

growl.notify(
        noteType = "Messages",
        title = "Title",
        description = "Description",
        icon = image,
        sticky = False,
        priority = 1,
)
```

Where image is just a plain old PNG.

Next I am trying to make a custom icon where I am adding some text (just numbers) to that PNG.  After some searching came up with this:

```
image = cv2.imread('image.png',0)
 cv2.putText(image, text='40', org=(10,10),
     fontFace= cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, fontScale=0.2, color=(0,0,0),
     thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
```

called before the growl notification and I get this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gntp/notifier.py", line 133, in notify
    if icon:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I realize now that OpenCV converts this to some kind of array.  How do I 'convert' this image back to a PNG etc. that growl is expecting.  I am looking to NOT save the dynamic image each time but I can if that's the only way.

I am sure this is probably trivial but its not obvious to me with my beginners opencv and python knowledge.  Also the solution does not need to be OpenCV based.  It was just the first one I found.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of your `growl.notify` call:

```
icon = image,
```

`image` is expected to be an [icon URL path](https://github.com/kfdm/gntp/blob/772a5f4db3707ea0253691d930bf648d1344913a/gntp/notifier.py#L110).

However, it looks like the `image` you create is actually an array, and Python doesn't know how to handle that when trying to see whether it is "true" or not [here](https://github.com/kfdm/gntp/blob/772a5f4db3707ea0253691d930bf648d1344913a/gntp/notifier.py#L133).

Comment: I clarified my question - I forgot the part of the working code that reads the image in via open then read.   You can use the file path or image open: https://pythonhosted.org/gntp/

Comment: It looks like you're opening an image file already (`image.png`) and then putting text on to it. Can you not use the file path to `image.png`?

Comment: I could I guess but it's not ideal.  The newly edited image is in memory already and seems there should be a way to feed this indirect to growl.

Comment: Did some more digging - I may want to use 'pillow' to add the text vs OpenCV.  It seems much easier.

Comment: Either way, since the `growl.notify` call expects a path, it seems like you'd need to at least have a temporary file for your icon construction so that you can pass that into the function.

Comment: If you see my first comment the python growl can be be a read file not just a path to one.  It can also be a URL to an image.  https://pythonhosted.org/gntp/